# Does .swp file affect the real file?

Tags: linux, iptables, swp

I was editing a file using the following command `vi /etc/iptables/rules.v4` file and my terminal crashed.
When I again tried to edit the same file I got the following message

```
       E325: ATTENTION
    Found a swap file by the name "/etc/iptables/rules.v4.swp"
              .
    .
    .
    .
    
    (1) Another program may be editing the same file.
        If this is the case, be careful not to end up with two
        different instances of the same file when making changes.
        Quit, or continue with caution.
    
    (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
        If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r /etc/iptables/rules.v4"
        to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
        If you did this already, delete the swap file "/etc/iptables/rules.v4"
        to avoid this message.
    
    Swap file "/etc/iptables/rules.v4.swp" already exists!
    [O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

My question is will this affect my original rules.v4 file?
As after this is stopped working on the file
I am completely new to linux

Answer (score 0):

swap file is a temporary file that is generated by vim to keep track of changes you have made in case of a crash. If the file rules.v4 is ok, you can delete it. Otherwise I strongly recommand to recover it, save it, and remove the .swp file. note that as long as you don't save, the Recover option will not write in the rules.v4

Comment: I don't want to recover the the changes made when it crashed. What will happen if I choose the delete option when this message appears again? Will it delete the .swp file created?  I want the original file to start making the changes again.

Comment: it will just delete the swap file, nothing else. You also can delete it manually using `rm /etc/iptables/rules.v4.swp` and you can check the current content of your file using `cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4`